# Insertion into sorted linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to add elements into a sorted linked list. when I try to add an element which is smaller than an existing element or smaller than the first element. it starts repeating. can someone help me with this?

thanks in advance

```
struct node {
    int key;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *init() {
    struct node *head = 0;
    return head;
}

void create(struct node **head, int num) {
    struct node *tmp = *head;
    struct node *prev = NULL;
    struct node *new = calloc(1, sizeof(struct node));
    new->key = num;
    prev = tmp;
    if (*head == NULL)
        *head = new;
    while (tmp != NULL && tmp->key < num) {
        prev = tmp;
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    new->next = tmp;
    if (prev != NULL)
        prev->next = new;
}

int main() {
    int op;
    int num;
    struct node *head;
    head = init();
    do {
        printf("\n Menu \n 1.Insert \n 2.delete element \n 3.display List 
    \n 4. end program ");
        printf("n \n \n please enter an option :     ");
        scanf("%d", &op);
        switch (op) {
          case 1:
            printf("Enter data:");
            scanf("%d", &num);
            create(&head, num);
            break;
          case 2:
            printf("Enter data:");
            scanf("%d",&num);
            delete(&head, num);
            break;
          case 4:
            free(head);
            exit(0);
          default:
            printf("\n enter an option : ");
        }
    } while(1);
}
```

This is what I get:

[image: program output]

Answer (score 1):

Your `create` function has multiple problems:

- it should be renamed `append_node` or something more explicit.
- you should avoid C++ keywords such as `new` and `delete` as it may confuse some editors and readers.
- you should test for memory allocation failure and return `NULL`, otherwise return the new node pointer so as to allow the caller to test for error.
- you mis-handle the case where `num` is smaller than the `key` of the head node: the new node: you set the `next` pointer to the previous node in the list, which is the head node, effectively creating a cycle.

Here is a corrected version:

```
struct node *append_node(struct node **head, int num) {
    struct node *tmp, *new_node;

    new_node = calloc(1, sizeof(*new_node));
    if (new_node == NULL)
        return NULL;
    new_node->key = num;
    tmp = *head;
    if (tmp == NULL || tmp->key > num) {
        /* insert at the head */
        new_node->next = tmp;
        *head = new_node;
    } else {
        /* locate the insertion point */
        while (tmp->next != NULL && tmp->next->key <= num)
            tmp = tmp->next;
        new_node->next = tmp;
        tmp->next = new_node;
    }
    return new_node;
}
```

Note that there is a shorter version using a double pointer to locate the insertion point, but it is more difficult to understand:

```
struct node *append_node(struct node **head, int num) {
    struct node *new_node;

    new_node = calloc(1, sizeof(*new_node));
    if (new_node != NULL) {
        new_node->key = num;
        while (*head != NULL && (*head)->key < num)
            head = &(*head)->next;
        new_node->next = *head);
        *head = new_node;
    }
    return new_node;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you insert an element smaller or equal than the first element, you never go into the while loop. Therefore the code executed creates a cycle in your list because `prev` and `tmp` are the same.

Here is the code executed when you don't go in the loop:

```
prev = tmp;
...
new->next = tmp;
if (prev != NULL)
    prev->next = new; // You create the cycle here.
```